# Allow multiple Python GUIs to run the same exe simultaneously

Tags: windows, multithreading, python-2.7, user-interface

A Python GUI that I develop executes an exe file in the same directory. I need to allow the user to open multiple instances of the GUI. This results in the same exe being called simultaneously and raises the following error: `the process can not access the file because it is being used by another process`. I use a dedicated thread in the python GUI to run the exe.

How can I allow the multiple GUIs to run the same exe simultaneously?

I would appreciate code examples.

Following is the thread. The run includes the execution of the exe. This exe was made using fortran.

```
class LineariseThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, parent):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self._parent = parent


def run(self):

    self.p = subprocess.Popen([exe_linearise], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    print threading.current_thread()

    print "Subprocess started"
    while True:
        line = self.p.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break      
        print line.strip()
        self._parent.status.SetStatusText(line.strip())
        # Publisher().sendMessage(('change_statusbar'), line.strip())
        sys.stdout.flush()

    if not self.p.poll():
        print " process done"
        evt_show = LineariseEvent(tgssr_show, -1)
        wx.PostEvent(self._parent, evt_show)


def killtree(self, pid):  
    print pid
    parent = psutil.Process(pid)
    print "in killtree sub: "
    for child in parent.get_children(recursive=True):
        child.kill()
    parent.kill()



def abort(self):
    if self.isAlive():
        print "Linearisation thread is alive"

        # kill the respective subprocesses
        if not self.p.poll():
            # stop them all
            self.killtree(int(self.p.pid))


        self._Thread__stop()
        print str(self.getName()) + " could not be terminated"

        self._parent.LineariseThread_killed=True
```

Comment: You do not show the code being used to create the subprocess, identify the exe or the name of the file, so it is hard to know why it is failing to execute multiple instances. Note that many exe's will not allow multiple instances of themselves to run under any circumstances, but we have no way of knowing if this is the case because you have not told us what exe it is :-)

Comment: please post the whole traceback of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a way to avoid the error. It was actually not the execution of the exe raised the error. The error raised when the exe accesses the other files which are locked by another instance of the same exe. Therefore, I decided not to allow multiple instance of exe to run. Instead, I thought of allowing multiple cases to be opened within a single instance. That way I can manage the process threads to avoid the above mentioned issue.

I should mention that the comments given to me helped me to study the error messages in detail to figure out what was really going on.